# Jquery UI Tabs: show events fired before add one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, tabs

I'm using the Jquery Ui example for manipulating tabs as in this page http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation. If no tab is created when i create the first one and create a var in the add event and then write alert(var_created) in the show event it doesn't work telling that the var is undefined, with the second, ther and so on tabs there are no problems.

I've created a script at jsfiddle for showing it:

now it should print an alert but it doesn't work and if you try you can see the error with a jslint taht tell the var is not defined http://jsfiddle.net/paglia_s/5GU8M/1/

There is a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

remove var

var var1 = "try"; should be var1 = "try";

I corrected it on your link http://jsfiddle.net/5GU8M/4/

For the sake of clarity, here's the explanation :

if you use 'var myvar = 1', the variable will only be active INSIDE the function in which it is used.

if you only declare 'myvar = 1' the variable is global and will work outside you jquery function, and you'll be able to call it from anywhere in the script.

Comment: ok but the problem is another also so when the first tab is created it doesn't work as you can see form your link

Comment: Apparently you or someone edited it back. http://jsfiddle.net/6fH4v/ here's a fork, try on the fork, you WILL see the alert.

Comment: are you sure of the link? it work as before the only difference is that now the var befor var1 is missing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jsFiddle. Are my changes saved automatically?

You have to define the variable in the upper scope. Otherwise this var is not defined outside.

I've done the following:

```
var var1 = "";

$(function() {
var $tab_title_input = $("#tab_title"),
    $tab_content_input = $("#tab_content");
var tab_counter = 0;

// tabs init with a custom tab template and an "add" callback filling in the content
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    add: function(event, ui) {
        var tab_content = $tab_content_input.val() || "Tab " + tab_counter + " content.";
        $(ui.panel).append("<p>" + tab_content + "</p>");
        var1 = "try";

    },

    show: function(event, ui) {

        alert(var1);

    }
});
```

Comment: In jsFiddle, there is a save button at the top. If you press it, you end up on a new url which you can share here and contains the code you had when you pressed the save button.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a couple of problems that you need to understand: variable scope and executing order.

**Variable scope**: Variables declared with `var` are local scope (to the closest function). Variables declared without `var` are global scope.

**Executing order**: When a tab is added to a jQuery Tabs control without any existing tab, `tabsshow` event is executed before `tabsadd` event. So, `var1` would not be defined when the first tab is added, hence the variable undefined error.

You can simply check whether `var1` is defined before using it:

```
if (typeof(var1) !== 'undefined') alert(var1);
```

Or, rearrange your code.

See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/6fH4v/1/.